# django-rest-auth reset password email contains 'example.com ' domain instead of site_domain

Tags: django, django-templates, django-rest-auth

I'm using `django-rest-auth` in my project and want to customize the email template used when resetting a password. If I send a POST request at `/rest-auth/password/reset/` with user email the request works but the email I receive is:

**email:**

```
from **webmaster@localhost** via ...


...

http://**example.com**/reset/ZGJjNjU2MjAtZjdjNy00MDdjLTkyZDctZDAwZGM2M2IzMmU4/4ys-09e6403c9784bea04986/

...
```

basically I want the domain `example` to be the domain of the project as well as the sender email to be a custom email.

I saw that I could create a `/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html` file and makes changes there. The line I need to change is:

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

- Is there a way to pass the project domain without hard coding it?
- How can I change the sender's email address to a custom one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Registration uses `django-allauth` which in turn uses the `sites` framework to populate emails. You should browse to the admin site and modify your default `site` (the one with an `id` of `1`).

See [post installation steps](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html?highlight=sites#post-installation) for `django-allauth`:

> Add a `Site` for your domain, matching `settings.SITE_ID` (`django.contrib.sites` app).

Comment: Note this changes the URL. To change the 'from' address put something like this in your settings.py: DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'My Site <noreply@mysite.com>'